# Change Website from Plain HTML to Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a static html website that I need to convert to Wordpress. I was able to successfully load wordpress on my hosting and configured a theme. However, the front end still displays the original html page. I need the whole website to be converted to wordpress, but I can't figure out where to add the htaccess and index.php files as I read from a blog. Someone help out.

Thanks

Sam

Comment: Sorry mate. This is not the correct forum for this kind of question. Here we help with programming.

Answer (score 1):

1) you're kind of asking for the whole of how the internet operates. I'm not saying that to be confrontational, just know that you'll likely be downvoted for such an impossible question.

2) more to the point, your server is looking for a directory index. In general, most servers look for index.html, index.htm, index.php, and then others, but in that order. If it encounters index.html in your directory then it stops and says that is the file to load.

3) you can get around this by changing the name of your file.

```
"index.html" -> "index_OLD.html" (or any name not index.html)
```

4) you can also change the way your server processes the index order using the DirectoryIndex directive in your HTAccess file. Ask your hosting provider about how to do this and if it's supported (although, I don't recommend you do this, it's just an available option).

5) your wordpress install should be in the root directory. That is to say, your .htaccess and index.php files should live in the same directory that your current index.html file lives in. Once the html file has a different name, the server will locate the php file and use it to server up as the directory index.

6) good luck friend!

Comment: This of course is a cursory and fast explanation. This isn't the place for this question and it'll likely get removed.

Comment: Thanks. I think that I've learned something. Let me try it out.